Visual Studio is not being installed and I can't quit installing it
I'm new to Unity, making my first steps, but I got stuck with the installation of Visual Studio. It's not being installed and can't be cancelled.
I tried to add a module and Unity started the downloading of Visual Studio Community. And I can't stop it. How to quit installing it?


I'm assuming this is on Windows.

If you are really sure you want to stop it in the middle of its process, you can use the Task Manager to stop it.
But if it really is doing something, this could leave a big mess in your filesystem. Take care.
